# Issue with nested a hrefs

Tags: html, css

How can I make the entire teal box (class name nav-about) click-able when I hover my mouse over the box while having nested  a hrefs? Is this possible?

**JSFIDDLE LINK http://jsfiddle.net/K8w4g/1/**

HTML

```
<a href="about.html">
<div class="nav-about">about
    <div class="sub-nav-about">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="1">1. one</a> </li>
            <li><a href="2">2. two</a></li>
            <li><a href="3">3. three</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-about {
float: left;
width: 254px;
height: 150px;
color: blue;
background-color: teal;
}

.sub-nav-about {
width: 150px;
}

.sub-nav-about ul {
list-style:none;
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: You can't have nested links, imagine if u want to click on a child link, you click on the parent...

Comment: Why not use javascript `onclick`?

Comment: Also don't forget you shouldn't place block elements (divs) inside inline elements (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.  However, you can achieve this through javascript, using `onclick`:

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='about.html'" class="nav-about">about
    <div class="sub-nav-about">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="1">1. one</a> </li>
            <li><a href="2">2. two</a></li>
            <li><a href="3">3. three</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

And you can still click the links inside the `div`.

Another solution would be to replace `div` with `span`, because it is only valid to wrap an `a` tag around some elements like `span`, so your new code would look like this:

```
<a href="about.html"> <span onclick="window.location.href='about.html'" class="nav-about">about
            <div class="sub-nav-about">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="1">1. one</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="2">2. two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="3">3. three</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
</a>
```